# how to repeat the audio wav file such that it becomes at least 6-seconds long in python

Tags: python, audio, wav, librosa

I am working on a sound classification problem and I want that my audio file should be atleast 6 second long. If it is not I want to extend it by running in the loop. and then find its STFT which is in librosa library of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help a bit

```
import math
import soundfile as sf
import numpy as np
import librosa

data, samplerate = sf.read('test1.wav')
channels = len(data.shape)
length_s = len(data)/float(samplerate)
if(length_s < 6.0):
    n = math.ceil(6*samplerate/len(data))
if(channels == 2):
    data = np.tile(data,(n,1))
else:
    data = np.tile(data,n)
sf.write('new.wav', data, samplerate)
# now calculate stft for each channel if stereo
```